# PHP using preg_replace to create a BB code help please

Tags: php, preg-replace

So I'm currently creating a project and in this project it requires a user to add information about their server/game.

I'm making the information field a little unique by adding some BB codes, and so far I've added nearly all but I need one small help.

I want add to add

`[img w=100 h=100]IMG link here[/img]`

the "100" means the amount, that was just a random number. Here is my PHP code that used:

`preg_replace('/\[img w=(.*?) h=(.*?)](.*?)\[\/img\]/i', '<img src="$3" height="$2" width="$1" draggable="false" />', $str);
'`

but the code returns this: 
`<img src="IMG LINK" height="100 h=100" draggable="false" />`

if anyone could help me I'd appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works correctly (PHP 5.2.8):

```
$str = "[img w=100 h=200]IMG link here[/img]";

echo preg_replace('/\[img w=(.*?) h=(.*?)](.*?)\[\/img\]/i', '<img src="$3"     height="$2" width="$1" draggable="false" />', $str);
```

Outputs

```
<img src="IMG link here" height="200" width="100" draggable="false" />
```

If you are getting different results, share your PHP version and example similar to mine above.